# Select + option - дата рождения. как сделать?

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

php

```
 <select name='day' id='day'>
        <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>День</option>
        <?php
            for($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++){
            echo "<option value=\"". $day ."\">$day</option>\n"; } ?>
        </select>
        <select name='month' id='month'>
        <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Месяц</option>
                   <?php
                        for($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++){
                            switch($month){
                                case 1: $month_name = "января"; break;
                                case 2: $month_name = "февраля"; break;
                                case 3: $month_name = "марта"; break;
                                case 4: $month_name = "апреля"; break;
                                case 5: $month_name = "мая"; break;
                                case 6: $month_name = "июня"; break;
                                case 7: $month_name = "июля"; break;
                                case 8: $month_name = "августа"; break;
                                case 9: $month_name = "сентября"; break;
                                case 10: $month_name = "октября"; break;
                                case 11: $month_name = "ноября"; break;
                                case 12: $month_name = "декабря"; }
                            echo "<option value=\"". $month."\"> $month_name</option>\n"; }?>
        </select>
    <select name='year' id='year'>
    <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Год</option>
                    <?php
                    for($year = date("Y") - 80; $year <= date("Y"); $year++){
                        echo "<option value=\"". $year ."\">$year</option>\n";}?>
    </select>
```

js

```
$('#day').change = $("#year").change = $("#month").change(function check_date(){
                var year = parseInt(document.getElementById('year').value);
                var month = parseInt(document.getElementById('month').value);
            var md;
                if(year % 4 == 0){
                    switch(month){
                        case 2: md = 29; break;
                        case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11: md = 30; break;
                        default: md = 31;
                    }
                }else{
                    switch(month){
                        case 2: md = 28; break;
                        case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11: md = 30; break;
                        default: md = 31;
                    }
                }
            // var select = document.getElementById('day');
       // select.options.length = 0;
    // for (var i = 1; i <= md; i++){
        // var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
       //  option.innerHTML = option.value = i;
        // select.appendChild(option);}});
```

Ошибка: Выбираешь День, потом месяц, потом год.После выбор года,скидывается день, а хотелось бы, чтоб выбранные день так и остался выбранным, а не скидывался. Никак не пойму как это  сделать.
P.s. буду благодарен если поможете или если поделитесь ссылками на понятный принцип даты рождения.

Comment: лучше не вручную проверять валидность даты, а используя объект Date, создаете объект с вашей датой. потом сверяете с тем что получилось. (getMonth итд)

Comment: Судя по коду JS пользователь ОБЯЗАН выбирать только в таком порядке: год, месяц, день.
Выбираешь месяц - select #day переписывается, выбираешь год - select #day снова переписывается.
И скажите, пожалуйста, зачем так извращаться? первая строка jquery, а потом чистый js? Может уже что-то одно выбрать? код будет читабельней, по крайней мере, не говоря уже об отказе от загрузки jquery на страницу, если он больше нигде не используется.

Answer (score 1):

Прислушался к мнению Eicto и fremail. Поэтому я сделал объявление события через jquery,а выполнение чисто js.

```
$("#year").change = $("#month").change(function(){
        var year = document.getElementById('year').value,
         month = document.getElementById('month').value,
        md = (new Date(year, month, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)).getDate();
        var select = document.getElementById('day');
            select.options.length = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= md; i++){
                    var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
                    option.innerHTML = option.value = i;
                    select.appendChild(option);}    
        });
```

Comment: > выполнение чисто js.

Ну зачем? Все, jQuery подгрузился, он уже здесь. Разница в производительности не будет заметна.

Answer (score 0):

1) Меняешь порядок select'ов: год, месяц, день
2) К select'ам месяца и дня добавляешь disabled
3) К JS дописываешь в конец:

```
if (year>0) $('#month').attr('disabled', 'false');
if (month>0) $('#day').attr('disabled', 'false');
```

4) Убери обработчик события с #day, он тебе не нужен